# What to do with trailing slash in $HOME on CentOS?

Tags: environment-variables, troubleshooting

I have a little project server sandbox running CentOS.

Setting up a new server package, I realized I needed to add new directory to the path and I found `$HOME` has a trailing slash for the main user.

I can't find where this has been set. It's not in,

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile.d
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try `getenw passwd username`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `$HOME` originates from the `/etc/passwd` file. You can use `usermod --home /home/user user` as root to change the home directory of `user` to be `/home/user`. The advantage of using `usermod` rather than editing `/etc/passwd` directly is that `usermod` will do a bit of validation and guard against race conditions if multiple changes to `/etc/passwd` are applied in parallel.

The trailing slash in `$HOME` is unusual but should be harmless. Even if it results in scripts producing path entries with double slashes in them, those will work exactly the same as single slashes.

Comment: "The trailing slash in $HOME is unusual but should be harmless."
the side effect is `$PWD` never match `$HOME`, while [bash interpret `\w` in `PS1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html), `\w` won't show as `~` even if current dir is `$HOME`.